# what is best way of creating padding around 2D array with javascript

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, 2d

Looking for the best, meaning the least complex O(*n*) way of adding padding around a 2d array using javascript. The 'edge' should be generated. The goal is to add 0 to the edge of the 2d array. The example below does work but could be better. Also trying not to use a double for loop. A recursive function might be better, note that the start array could be any value, including all 0. 'fill' is just the value in the padding, and could be anything. Last what about a 2d array of any length?

```
let arr = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1], 
  [1, 0, 0, 1], 
  [1, 0, 0, 1], 
  [1, 1, 1, 1]
];

function addPadding(array, fill) {
    let edge = [fill,fill,fill,fill,fill,fill];
    for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        array[i].push(0);
        array[i].unshift(0);
    }
    array.push(edge);
    array.unshift(edge);
    return array;
};

arr = addPadding(arr, 0);

console.log('Finally');
console.table(arr);

/**
* expected output
*┌─────────┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┬───┐
*│ (index) │ 0 │ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │ 4 │ 5 │
*├─────────┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┼───┤
*│    0    │ 0 │ 0 │ 0 │ 0 │ 0 │ 0 │
*│    1    │ 0 │ 1 │ 1 │ 1 │ 1 │ 0 │
*│    2    │ 0 │ 1 │ 0 │ 0 │ 1 │ 0 │
*│    3    │ 0 │ 1 │ 0 │ 0 │ 1 │ 0 │
*│    4    │ 0 │ 1 │ 1 │ 1 │ 1 │ 0 │
*│    5    │ 0 │ 0 │ 0 │ 0 │ 0 │ 0 │
*└─────────┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┴───┘
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are just looking at creating padding of some value, be it an int or string, we could do this. This method does not account for different padding dimensions. The overall complexity is about 4.

```
let arr = [
    [1, 1, 1, 1], 
    [1, 0, 0, 1], 
    [1, 0, 0, 1], 
    [1, 1, 1, 1]
  ];
  
  function addPadding(array, fill) {
    const edge = Array(array.length + 2).fill(fill);
    array = array.map(a => {
        a.push(fill);
        a.unshift(fill);
        return a;
    });
    array.push(edge);
    array.unshift(edge);
    return array;
  };
  
  arr = addPadding(arr, 0);
  
  console.log('Finally');
  console.table(arr);
```

Comment: This is nice too. What's the complexity of my answer, just curious?

Comment: I don't know why, but it doesn't work if applied multiple times. e.g. `arr = [[1]]; console.log(addPadding(addPadding(arr, 0), 0))` will yield a none-square 2d array. I've rewritten it to use destructuring to make it work (`return [fill, ...a, fill]` and `return [edge, ...array, edge]` instead of modifying the original array)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all the arrays are same size. What I'll do is...

1. I'll first convert each line into string.
2. I'll then pad them with zeros in front and back of each string.
3. Convert them back into arrays.
4. Pad the number of strings front and back of the main array and convert them as arrays.
5. You can prepend `+` in front of a string to make them into an integer. Here `+` is a unary operator.

Not sure about the complexity, but I believe, this should be easier. I am not using any loops except two maps to convert arrays to string and back to arrays.

```js
let arr = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1]
];
arr = arr.map(a => "0" + a.join("") + "0");
const pad = "0".repeat(arr[0].length);
arr.unshift(pad);
arr.push(pad);
arr = arr.map(a => a.split("").map(n => +n));
console.table(arr);
```

Some changes and making it as a function like yours:

```js
let array = [
  [1, 1, 1, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 0, 0, 1],
  [1, 1, 1, 1]
];

function addPadding(arr, fill) {
  arr = arr.map(a => fill + a.join("") + fill);
  const pad = fill.repeat(arr[0].length);
  arr.unshift(pad);
  arr.push(pad);
  arr = arr.map(a => a.split("").map(n => +n));
  return arr;
}

console.table(addPadding(array, "0"));
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing. There are some good ideas here, love the use of the map to copy the array. Also, your use of the join method during the copy of the array is great. The returned array from the function is still a string type. Also, the use of repeat() means fill now has to be a string.

Comment: @JoshuaConnor Thanks for letting me know about the issue. I have fixed them. See the point #5: You can prepend `+` in front of a string to make them into an integer. Here `+` is a unary operator. What do you think now?

Comment: Yes that is a good fix, I made some changes where the fill can be any value when entering the function,  making use of javascripts other functions. Thanks again for posting.